# Fade Desktop Wallpaper in Applescript (Mac OS X)

Tags: background, applescript, desktop, fade, wallpaper

I have written an AppleScript which, among other things, sets my desktop background.  However,  using AppleScript's "set picture" changes the background abruptly - it doesn't look too good.  Is there a way to get the nice fade effect that is used when you cycle the background via the Desktop & Screen Saver preferences' "Change Picture" setting?

Ideally, I'd like to do this in AppleScript, but if it's possible in Cocoa (or something else), please do let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question!

It's not *exactly* what I was looking for, but close enough:

```
set picture rotation to 1 -- turn on wallpaper cycling
set change interval to -1 -- force a change to happen right now
delay 1.5 -- wait a bit to allow for the fade transition - you may want to play w/ this #
set picture of item N of theDesktops to POSIX file ("yourfilenamehere.png") -- set wallpaper to wallpaper you want
set picture rotation to 0  -- turn off wallpaper cycling
```

By taking advantage of Apple's built-in wallpaper changer, you can get the fade effect in AppleScript, but you'll need to put whatever images you want to change between in a directory together and select it either in the Desktop & Screen Saver preferences or programmatically.

Also, `set picture rotation to 1` seems to automatically change the wallpaper to what I think is the first image (alphabetically) in that directory - I didn't bother to test this, though, it didn't matter for my purposes.  The delay of 1.5 allows for a bit of blinking, but since the image I was using was a TARDIS, that's acceptable and actually made for a cool effect (so long as we watch out for weeping angels!)

Answer (score 0):

The original question is more than ten years old, but I suppose it still makes sense to post another contribution — after all I ran into this article because I was searching for it.

After playing with AppleScript I wasn't able to find any satisfactory solution. So I used an alternate approach: let the system do its job as usual without tweaking with it, but changing the images it manages on the fly.

In other words: assuming that `$TEMP_WALLPAPER_FOLDER` is an empty working folder, I configured System Preferences to use it as the folder with background pictures, I disabled random order and set to change background every 5 seconds.

Then this little piece of `bash` script, called every five minutes, does the job. Assuming that `$IMAGE` is the new image to use:

1. It links `$IMAGE` to the temporary folder with a link whose name is the current timestamp (it isn't necessary to have a timestamp, a progressive index would do, but a timestamp is easier to manage); at this point there are two links in the folder, the previous image and the new one.
2. It waits for 8 seconds: in this way we are sure that a 5-seconds change happens, so the system finds the new image and switches to it; and that it happens only once, so it doesn't switch again, back to the previous image.
3. It removes the link to the previous image; now there is again only one link in the folder, so when the 5-seconds period expires again the system finds only the current image. I assume that the system is smart enough not to waste CPU in this circumstance, that is it doesn't start a fade transition to the same image.

```
        TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        ln -fs "$IMAGE" "$TEMP_WALLPAPER_FOLDER/$TIMESTAMP.jpg"
        sleep 8
        find "$TEMP_WALLPAPER_FOLDER" -type l | grep -v "$TIMESTAMP" | xargs rm
```